# How to put a redstone block in clock mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I saw [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=3m35s&v=VCKMv1i-wPE) by SethBling.
(The video is caught up to the moment of my question)

He says "Make sure these are in clock mode" what does he mean by clock mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a note, Sethbling asks you to import the schematic.
Anyways...

**What Sethbling refers to as clock mode is a redstone block that is continually being replaced.**

As you see in the video, as he destroys the block, it immediately appears again.
This is a neat little trick - you can make a redstone clock that signals up to 20 times per second.

To do this, have a layout like this:

```
z-- <-    [C][R][C]    -> z++
```

Where `C`s are the command blocks and `R` is the redstone block.
Open up F3 and make sure that the `z coordinate` of the right command block > redstone block > left command block.

**If you want to line it up over a different axis, just change the following codes. Remember - first x, then y, finally z.**

On the leftmost command block, type this:

```
/fill ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~1 redstone_block
```

On the rightmost:

```
/fill ~ ~ ~-1 ~ ~ ~-1 air
```

Finally, put the redstone block in the middle.
Now, it will magically become the fastest clock in Minecraft. (As far as we know.)

Comment: If it's a 20 Hz clock, then it is, by necessity the fastest clock in Minecraft, and indeed, the fastest clock possible: Redstone updates at 20 Hz, so no faster clock could exist.

Comment: @WillihamTotland redstone updates at 10Hz, the game itself updates at 20Hz.

Comment: @WillihamTotland It's unlikely that there's a faster clock, but I wouldn't dismiss the possibility entirely. Previously it wasn't thought possible to have redstone turn on and off in the exact same tick, but that's exactly how the 20Hz clock works, by exploiting order of command execution. Not theoretically impossible to find some other exploit that allows for a faster clock.

Comment: @colorfusion: If the game only updates at 20 Hz, then that _is_ the fastest clock. It might be possible to make a _visually_ faster clock, but it will be indistinguishable from a 20 Hz clock for all other purposes.

Comment: @WillihamTotland The same logic was used to say that, since redstone needs to turn on and off to activate something again, and the game only updates at 20Hz, then there can't be a block faster than 10Hz. I doubt that there *is* a faster clock than what we have, but considering the one we have is already exploiting unintended game elements, it's not completely unthinkable for something faster to emerge.

Comment: Well I knew about that trick but he broke it and it became stone not air.

Comment: @colorfusion I wouldn't doubt it. Minecraft is a mysterious thing and mojang and microsoft a more of a mystery. Dont get me started on Jeb...

Comment: @CoderKid, this command can be changed to have the 'in-between' block be anything; air is an example. I assume that if you used MCEdit to see his schematic, you should be able to check the command and the exact block he used.

Comment: Ok thank you :) I'll make sure I do that when I get a minute.

Answer (score 0):

clock mode means that 1 or maybe 2 command blocks are used to make clocks that to to the other commanc blocks. so basicly it is a clock made out of command blocks they are fast

if you want to make one the most easyest way to do this with only one command block is.

> /setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 minecraft:redstone_block 0 destroy

but if you want to make one like on sethblings video you need to do it like this

> /fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:redstone_block 0  destroy

so if you want to use it like in is video