# How do i make Tnt Have more explosion damage in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know how to make it longer with fuse but is there a way to make it more powerful?

Answer (score 6):

TNT's power cannot be changed in vanilla Minecraft. When TNT explodes the explosion damage will not stack with the explosion damage of other explosives exploding at the same time. Also there is no ExplosionRadius or ExplosionPower NBT tags for primed TNT. If you are a map maker and want more powerful TNT explosions, it can be done by replacing exploding primed TNT with creepers with a set explosion radius with 0 fuse.

More Power In TNT (Creeper) Via command blocks:

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add noFuse dummy
```

[Fill Clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/217275/how-to-put-a-redstone-block-in-clock-mode):

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=PrimedTnt] noFuse 1 {Fuse:0} //You can add more restrictions to the selector to only power up certain tnt
/execute @e[type=PrimedTnt,score_noFuse_min=1] summon Creeper ~ ~-1 ~ {Fuse:0,ExplosionRadius:<Explosion Radius>, ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:10,ShowParticles:0}]}
/kill @e[type=PrimedTnt,score_noFuse_min=1]
```

Comment: You may also want to make those creepers invisible.  I forget exactly how to do that off the top of my head, but it should be possible in the NBT tags.

Comment: Invisible is done by adding `ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Amplifier:1,Duration:1,ShowParticles:0}]` to the Creeper's NBT tag.

Comment: You can do it but its not mandatory

Answer (score 3):

Well, by "more explosion damage" you might mean one of two things;

- Increase the explosion's radius, or
- Increase the explosion's power

Although you can't increase the radius on a *single* block of TNT, you could simply detonate multiple TNTs one after the other.

As for increasing the power, you can't (at least, not in vanilla Minecraft). You see, every time something explodes, Minecraft has a number assigned which is it's power. This number is constant with each event, but may be different between events.

(i.e.: every creeper will explode with the same power [3], but that does not necessarily mean TNT will have the same power[4].)

Now, you're probably thinking "Oh, I'll detonate multiple TNTs at once." The problem is, each explosion is calculated independently of each other, and damage to a block is not cumulative.

For example:

Sandstone has a blast resistance of 4, therefore TNT can destroy it since its power (4) is greater than or equal to sandstone's blast resistance. But, a creeper cannot ever destroy sandstone since its power (3) is less than the blast resistance. Since explosions are not cumulative, no amount of creeper explosions will destroy it.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion

Comment: You can make a creeper destroy sandstone, either by charging it or changing its nbt

Answer (score -2):

```
/summon creeper ~ ~ 5 ~ {ExplosionPower:3}
```

Comment: Could you explain how and why this works?

Comment: Because, as explained in the other answer, tnt's power cannot be changed. A workaround however, is to use creepers instead as their power CAN be changed

Answer (score -3):

Using a crafting table, fill all nine slots with tnt. This will create super tnt. Fill all nine slots with super tnt. This will create nuke tnt.
Note: it is impossible to run away from the blast radius of the nuke. Go on creative to see the results.